# Configuring apoc.refactor.MergeNodes()

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I'm testing the apoc procedure on this set-up:

```
CREATE (:testNode{id:"1"})-[:TAGS{id:"r1"}]->(:tag{id:"h"})
CREATE (:testNode{id:"2"})-[:TAGS{id:"r2"}]->(:tag{id:"H"})
```

And then running this:

```
MATCH (htag:tag), (gtag:tag)
WHERE htag.id=toLower(gtag.id) AND htag<>gtag
WITH htag, gtag LIMIT 1
CALL apoc.refactor.mergeNodes([htag, gtag], {id:'discard'}) YIELD node
RETURN node
```

As I understand it, *{id:'discard'}* is supposed to indicate that if *htag.id* exists, it will be kept and *gtag.id* will be thrown out. Instead, it seems to be keeping *gtag.id*.

What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You incorrectly filled the config:

```
CALL apoc.refactor.mergeNodes([htag, gtag], {properties: {id:'discard'}}) YIELD node
```

[ https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_merging_nodes ]